# CodeIgniter 3.1.2 Internal server Error in Image upload

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am getting :

```
500 Internal server error
```

on Image  upload through **AJAX**. When it reaches:

```
 $this->upload->do_upload('filename');
```

it produce this error. I search every where but no solution found.

**My code is:**

```
foreach($_FILES as $key_img=>$row_img){
    if(!empty($row_img['name'])){
        $image_path = './assets/images/';
        $config['upload_path'] = $image_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png";
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key_img))
        {
            $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $userfile = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }

    }
}
```

The error reported in Console where as no response on Network Tab.

Comment: is there anything in your logs?

Comment: No my cPanel Error log is empty.

Comment: Is error reporting and debugging turned on?

Comment: yes, error reporting is on. I get other php errors. But this is weird, get 500 internal server error

Comment: Is php_fileinfo.dll enabled (uncommented) in php.ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with the codeigniter 3.1.2 upload.php,
I have php7 but I get the 500 error.
My solution was to download codeigniter 3.0.6 and copy the file upload.php and paste it into system / libraries

Comment: Awesome thanks for the solution, i will try this.. Many thanks in advance, will get back to you soon.